# python sqlite3 List

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

I have a question about sqlite3 in python, it is about the list problem.
Here is the question:

**Write a function `getMay(dbName)` that takes as a parameter the filename of above database and returns two lists, one with the days and one with the temperatures at noon on those days.**

Here is My code:

```
import sqlite3

def getMay(dbName):
    conn = sqlite3.connect(dbName)
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute('select Day,Temp from May14 where Time= "12:00" order by Day ASC')
    print(cur.fetchall())
    cur.close()
    conn.close()
```

Here is my output:

> [(1, 13.7), (2, 11.1), (3, 12.2), (4, 13.2), (5, 12.9), (6, 12.5), (7,
>   9.6), (8, 11.6), (9, 13.2), (10, 19.2), (11, 21.7), (12, 15.2), (13, 11.9), (14, 16.4), (15, 12.2), (16, 10.1), (17, 9.8), (18, 16.2), (19, 21.5), (20, 17.8), (21, 17.0), (22, 18.6), (23, 16.5), (24, 21.2), (25, 25.4), (26, 27.8), (27, 27.3), (28, 13.7), (29, 15.0), (30,
>   22.5), (31, 21.0)]

But the correct output should look like:

```
([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20,
21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31], [13.7, 11.1, 12.2, 13.2,
12.9, 12.5, 9.6, 11.6, 13.2, 19.2, 21.7, 15.2, 11.9, 16.4, 12.2, 10.1,
9.8, 16.2, 21.5, 17.8, 17.0, 18.6, 16.5, 21.2, 25.4, 27.8, 27.3, 13.7,
15.0, 22.5, 21.0])
```

Anyone know how to solve this problem?
Please help! Thank!

Comment: So your output is essentially a Nx2 array, and you need a 2xN array. You should search for that ("transpose Python nested list" or similar).

Answer (score 0):

one easy solution could be this:

```
dayTemp_list = [(1, 13.7), (2, 11.1), (3, 12.2), (4, 13.2), (5, 12.9), (6, 12.5), (7, 9.6), (8, 11.6), (9, 13.2), (10, 19.2), (11, 21.7), (12, 15.2), (13, 11.9), (14, 16.4), (15, 12.2), (16, 10.1), (17, 9.8), (18, 16.2), (19, 21.5), (20, 17.8), (21, 17.0), (22, 18.6), (23, 16.5), (24, 21.2), (25, 25.4), (26, 27.8), (27, 27.3), (28, 13.7), (29, 15.0), (30, 22.5), (31, 21.0)]

days = []
temp = []
for i in dayTemp_list:
    days.append(i[0])
    temp.append(i[1])

result = (days,temp)
print result
```